# Access content in Windows Store package

Tags: windows-store-apps

The article 'How to load file resources' on MSDN and others, discuss ms-appx and ms-appdata URI schemes for addressing content in the application package.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781229.aspx

The problem is, I can't see any way to load anything other than image files. The XmlReader, for example, doesn't support these URI schemes and all the Windows.Storage.PathIO static read methods throw

> COMException: "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

Possibly the exception is caused by a bad URI/usage error. I know Silverlight used to throw this message for all sorts of reasons.

Has anyone been able to read non-image data from their package?

Luke

Answer (score 0):

I'm now able to answer my own question.

```
var f = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Data").AsTask().Result;
var i = f.GetFileAsync("Sample Data.xml").AsTask().Result;
var s = Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(i).AsTask().Result;

var r = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(s));
r.MoveToContent();

var x = r.ReadInnerXml();
```

Excuse the lack of awaits, its just experimental code.

I filed a connect bug for the XmlReader.Create method not accepting a package URI - it shouldn't be this hard, and what's the point of a package URI if nothing uses it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ms-appx` scheme with all WinRT APIs accepting URIs. You could rewrite your code like this (it also reads directly from `Stream` instead of loading complete file contents to `string` first):

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Data/Sample Data.xml"));
var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
reader.MoveToContent();
var result = reader.ReadInnerXml();
```

`PathIO` methods should also work fine. I just tried this:

```
var xml = await PathIO.ReadTextAsync("ms-appx:///Assets/Sample Data.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks Damir - using the OpenStreamForReadAsync API was my original effort, but I changed it while fiddling around. It's a shame the XmlReader doesn't just take the ms-appx URI, would have saved a couple of hours.